# Design a rest api which takes query param greater then some value

Tags: rest

I want to design a rest api which takes a query param greater then some value.

Example:

/v1/credit/credits?total_amount>100

So here I want to fetch list of credits record greater then 100.

What would be the appropriate approach to pass this total_amount in query param.

Answer (score 0):

As query parameters aren't SQL, the closest you can get is this:

`/v1/credit/credits?min_total_amount=100`

or

`/v1/credit/credits?minTotalAmount=100`

Camel- vs. snakecase is up to you.